# Android saveState of webview page

Tags: android, webview, rotation, savestate

I noticed that in the browser app, when I scroll down a webpage and rotate the screen, the location of the webpage stays

But when I try this in a webview of my own, the webpage (and everything else in the activity) reloads. I know about `onSaveInstanceState` but that takes Bundles of primitate data types, what about location within a webview?

I need to be able to rotate the screen without changing anything

Insight appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Avoid Activity restarting when rotation happens:

In your manifest, add android:configChanges="orientation" in activity node, then your Activity won't be restarted during rotation, instead Activity.onConfigurationChanged will be called.

Then only onLayout will be called, and loaded data will remain in memory.

Comment: and in `onLayout` that will detect rotation changes for me and I can still do some things there if necessary?

Comment: onLayout is called when layout changes, which may happen anytime also without rotation.
onConfigurationChanged is designed to report changes in configuration that you intent do handle yourself (such as rotation) and that you mark in manifest as such.